# Data Sets of SCOPUS, Web Of Science and/or Google Scholar

Tags: analysis

I need to access the data from both SCOPUS, Web Of Science and/or Google Scholar. The data is needed in the following form:

```
paper1 paper2 date1
paper3 paper4 date2
paper10 paper3 date3
.
.
```

where, `paperA paperB date` means: paperA cites paperB on 'date'.

I tried using [this API](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/04/06/Using-the-Scopus-api-with-xml-output/) to access citation data from scopus without any success. And I have no clue of getting this kind of data from Google Scholar or Web of science either. But I have seen a few papers making use of data from these portals. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you have access to SCOPUS and Web of Science? You or your university needs a license to even use the web interface. Using the API might be even more complex. In addition, I assume that the exact publishing dates aren't part of the metadata, at least not in Google Scholar.

Comment: Yes, My university has access to these portals.

Answer (score 1):

Neither WoS nor Scopus nor Google Scholar offer such data openly, not even with the usual licensed, university-mediated access.

However, there is a good and open alternative: *OpenCitations*' [COCI](https://opencitations.net/index/coci)-dataset.